# boost::asio custom handler allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost-asio

I have just tried to understand the boost::asio handler allocation example (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/allocation/server.cpp).

I know this is an oversimplified example for educational purposes but there is something I cannot understand: is there any case in which the class handler_allocator make use of the heap (in_use_ == true) because I cannot see it.

Every session has his own allocator and every time is like this: read and then write but you do not read until the write finishes. And also you can read in the documentation:

> The implementation guarantees that the deallocation will occur before the associated handler is invoked, which means the memory is ready to be reused for any new asynchronous operations started by the handler.

My question is: can you tell me an example where the allocation on the heap (in this example) occurs?

Extra: any one nows a little bit more complete example of handler custom allocations?

Comment: For a half duplex protocol, I find the Boost.Asio example to be fairly complete rather than oversimplified.  If you could elaborate as to what you expect in a more complete example, I would be glad to help.

Comment: That would be great, Tanner. As I wrote below I would like to generalize the allocator providing more than one block of memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, Boost.Asio does not guarantee that [`asio_handler_allocate()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_allocate.html) will only be invoked once for a single asynchronous operation.  Therefore, in the example, `handler_allocator` will allocate from the free store via operator `new()` if Boost.Asio decides it needs additional storage. The [Asynchronous Operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html) documentation states:

> If the implementation needs to allocate storage for an asynchronous operation, the implementation will perform `asio_handler_allocate(size, &h)`, [...]. Multiple storage blocks may be allocated for a single asynchronous operation.

The criteria for which the implementation uses to determine it needs to allocate storage is unspecified.  Additionally requirements for `asio_handler_*()` functions can be found in the [Handler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Handler.html) documentation.

With previous versions of Boost.Asio, the example may have performed multiple allocations per asynchronous operation.  A brief glance at the [revision history](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html) indicates effort has been spent to reduce the amount of handler copies.

Comment: I really like your answers, Tanner. What's your opinion about generalizing the allocator in the sense of having several boost::alligned_storage for minimizing heap allocations? That could work as expected? I mean, instead of directly ask to the heap if the storage is in use, provide another block of memory (or several blocks). What do you think?

Comment: @ChrisPeterson Glad my answers have been helpful.  An allocator implemented with a memory pool would work.  Although it may be worth considering [Boost.Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html) rather than numerous `aligned_storage` objects.  Profiling an application is the best way to determine the appropriate allocation strategy.  If fragmentation is an issue, then a memory pool can help mitigate the issue.  If the bottleneck is contention between thread allocations, then Google's [TCMalloc](https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/) can be helpful.